# alpaca-py StopOrderRequest bug related to status of bracket legs

Tags: python, api, alpaca

Using the [alpaca-py library](https://alpaca.markets/docs/python-sdk/index.html), I am trying to [create a new order](https://alpaca.markets/docs/python-sdk/api_reference/trading/orders.html#create-a-new-order) using the [StopOrderRequest](https://alpaca.markets/docs/python-sdk/api_reference/trading/requests.html#stoporderrequest) with [brackets](https://alpaca.markets/docs/trading/orders/#bracket-orders). The result is this error message:

```py
File "G:\...functions.py", line 80, in trading_client.submit_order(order_request)
File "C:\...\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\alpaca\trading\client.py", line 90, in submit_order
    return Order(**response)
  File "C:...\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\alpaca\trading\models.py", line 182, in __init__
    super().__init__(**data)
  File "pydantic\main.py", line 341, in pydantic.main.BaseModel.__init__
pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 2 validation errors for Order
legs -> 0 -> status
  value is not a valid enumeration member; permitted: 'new', 'partially_filled', 'filled', 'done_for_day', 'canceled', 'expired', 'replaced', 'pending_cancel', 'pending_replace', 'accepted', 'pending_new', 'accepted_for_bidding', 'stopped', 'rejected', 'suspended', 'calculated' (type=type_error.enum; enum_values=[<OrderStatus.NEW: 'new'>, <OrderStatus.PARTIALLY_FILLED: 'partially_filled'>, <OrderStatus.FILLED: 'filled'>, <OrderStatus.DONE_FOR_DAY: 'done_for_day'>, <OrderStatus.CANCELED: 'canceled'>, <OrderStatus.EXPIRED: 'expired'>, <OrderStatus.REPLACED: 'replaced'>, <OrderStatus.PENDING_CANCEL: 'pending_cancel'>, <OrderStatus.PENDING_REPLACE: 'pending_replace'>, <OrderStatus.ACCEPTED: 'accepted'>, <OrderStatus.PENDING_NEW: 'pending_new'>, <OrderStatus.ACCEPTED_FOR_BIDDING: 'accepted_for_bidding'>, <OrderStatus.STOPPED: 'stopped'>, <OrderStatus.REJECTED: 'rejected'>, <OrderStatus.SUSPENDED: 'suspended'>, <OrderStatus.CALCULATED: 'calculated'>])
legs -> 1 -> status
  value is not a valid enumeration member; permitted: 'new', 'partially_filled', 'filled', 'done_for_day', 'canceled', 'expired', 'replaced', 'pending_cancel', 'pending_replace', 'accepted', 'pending_new', 'accepted_for_bidding', 'stopped', 'rejected', 'suspended', 'calculated' (type=type_error.enum; enum_values=[<OrderStatus.NEW: 'new'>, <OrderStatus.PARTIALLY_FILLED: 'partially_filled'>, <OrderStatus.FILLED: 'filled'>, <OrderStatus.DONE_FOR_DAY: 'done_for_day'>, <OrderStatus.CANCELED: 'canceled'>, <OrderStatus.EXPIRED: 'expired'>, <OrderStatus.REPLACED: 'replaced'>, <OrderStatus.PENDING_CANCEL: 'pending_cancel'>, <OrderStatus.PENDING_REPLACE: 'pending_replace'>, <OrderStatus.ACCEPTED: 'accepted'>, <OrderStatus.PENDING_NEW: 'pending_new'>, <OrderStatus.ACCEPTED_FOR_BIDDING: 'accepted_for_bidding'>, <OrderStatus.STOPPED: 'stopped'>, <OrderStatus.REJECTED: 'rejected'>, <OrderStatus.SUSPENDED: 'suspended'>, <OrderStatus.CALCULATED: 'calculated'>])
```

Answer (score 1):

I spoke to Alpaca support. It turns out that the leg orders (take profit and stop loss) generate a status of 'held,' which has not yet been added to the alpaca-py library enums. The error can be ignored.